# How does the flash player play local mp4 file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, mp4

I want to play the local mp4 file in adobe flash player, the source code show following:

```
package
        {
           import flash.display.Sprite;
           import flash.net.NetConnection;
           import flash.net.NetStream;
           import flash.text.TextField;
           import flash.media.Video;

           public class Exploit extends Sprite
           {

              public function Exploit()
              {
                 greeting = new TextField();
                 super();
                 greeting.text = "Loading...";
                 greeting.x = 100;
                 greeting.y = 100;
                 addChild(greeting);
                 MyVideo = new Video();
                 addChild(MyVideo);
                 MyNC = new NetConnection();
                 MyNC.connect(null);
                 MyNS = new NetStream(MyNC);
                 MyVideo.attachNetStream(MyNS);
                 MyNS.play("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4");
              }

              public var MyNC:NetConnection;

              public var MyNS:NetStream;

              private var greeting:TextField;

              public var MyVideo:Video;
           }
        }
```

then I use mxmlc.exe to generate .swf file. Open the swf file, it works. But when I modify MyNS.play("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4") to MyNs.play("small.mp4"), and then use mxmlc.exe to generate .swf file. Open it, it cannot play the small.mp4 file.(Note: small.mp4 locates the same directory with swf file).

```
Anyone give me suggestion?
```

Comment: For anyone with same problem. Try setting your swf output options from _"access **network** files only"_ to being _"access **local** files only"_ then test again.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think flash supports MP4 natively. I would suggest looking at a codec

Here is the list of natively supported codecs by the Flash Player:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402866.html

If you need to play something not natively supported, there are external API's that will allow you to do so, just chose a Flash Sound API:

http://www.google.com.br/search?q=flash+sound+API

Comment: This is wrong. Flash has a built-in MPEG decoder (handles mp4, h264, mp3 & aac). The asker's problem lies in them trying to load a local file while the Flash output options were not set to "access local files only" by default these are set to "access network files only", there is no mention of them being changed, hence the problem....